# Combining multiple complex SELECT statements so they appear on one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to SQL so please be gentle. I've got a table that records temperature from various sensors in various locations. I'm happy to re-jig the database structure if it's easier.

The columns are: ID *int*, SensorID *tinyint*, LocationID *tinyint*, TempReadDT *datetime*, Temp (*decimal 4,1*)

The sensors record a reading every few mins and i'd like to have one stored proc to grab the following information for display on a summary page:

1. Current Indoor Temp (the latest reading from sensor 1)
2. Current Outdoor Temp (the latest reading from sensor 2)
3. Average indoor temp for last 24 hours
4. Average indoor temp for last 7 days
5. Last updated date time (the latest date recorded)

I've created the individual `SELECT` statements (below) but I'm unsure of how to combine them into one query so the data is returned on one row.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Temp AS "intTemp"
  FROM Temperature
 WHERE SensorID = 1
 ORDER BY ID DESC

SELECT TOP 1 Temp AS "extTemp"
  FROM Temperature
 WHERE SensorID = 2
 ORDER BY ID DESC

SELECT AVG(Temp) AS "avgTemp24h"
  FROM Temperature
 WHERE SensorID = 1
   AND TempReadDT >= DATEADD(DAY,-1, SYSDATETIME())

SELECT AVG(Temp) AS "avgTemp7d"
  FROM Temperature
 WHERE SensorID = 1
   AND TempReadDT >= DATEADD(DAY,-7, SYSDATETIME())

SELECT MAX(TempReadDT)
  FROM Temperature
```

Comment: If you show raw data and expected results, you should get better and faster answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   Max(case SensorID when 1 then Temp else null end) AS "intTemp",
   Max(case SensorID when 2 then Temp else null end) AS "intTemp",
   AVG(case 
           when SensorID = 1  
            AND TempReadDT >= DATEADD(DAY,-1, SYSDATETIME()) 
           then Temp else null end) AS "avgTemp24h",
   AVG(case 
           when SensorID = 1  
            AND TempReadDT >= DATEADD(DAY,-7, SYSDATETIME()) 
           then Temp else null end) AS "avgTemp7d",
   MAX(TempReadDT) MaxTemp
FROM Temperature
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, works perfectly. I'll read up more on how this case thing works :)

Answer (score 3):

I HATE cross joins, but...

```
Select * from 
(SELECT TOP 1 Temp AS "intTemp"
  FROM Temperature
 WHERE SensorID = 1
 ORDER BY ID DESC
) A
cross join
(SELECT TOP 1 Temp AS "extTemp"
  FROM Temperature
 WHERE SensorID = 2
 ORDER BY ID DESC
)B
cross join
(
SELECT AVG(Temp) AS "avgTemp24h"
  FROM Temperature
 WHERE SensorID = 1
   AND TempReadDT >= DATEADD(DAY,-1, SYSDATETIME())
)C
cross join
(
SELECT AVG(Temp) AS "avgTemp7d"
  FROM Temperature
 WHERE SensorID = 1
   AND TempReadDT >= DATEADD(DAY,-7, SYSDATETIME())
)D 
cross join
(
SELECT MAX(TempReadDT)
  FROM Temperature) E
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the sub queries and the alias the result for example

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2 from (select * from tbl1) as t1, (select * from tbl2) as t2
```